# Horizontal listview header text animation

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

Is there any way to create horizontal list view with header. I think Horizontal list view can be created via HorizontalScrollView component. As displayed in the tasks app (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWZPh.jpg) I've provided, both Grocery List and Work headers can be viewed in being in the grocery list. When I'm moving from Grocery List to Work, the header should move seamlessly as well. How to animate headers like that (so that they get placed while we are scrolling through lists)?

Thanks

here is the link for tasks free app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWZPh.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tasks` App (the screenshot you posted, and actually I am using it everyday) uses ViewPager with PagerTitleStrip.

If you use Eclipse, there is a default option that creates such activity.

[image]

The following XML code is automatically generated by Eclipse when I select `Swipe Views + Title Strip`.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!--
This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
titles for adjacent pages.
-->
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#33b5e5"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
```

Also try to check those:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html

**ADDED**

Automatically generated `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments for each of the
     * sections. We use a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will
     * keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it may be best
     * to switch to a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }        

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
     * sections of the app.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
                case 1: return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
                case 2: return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return textView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is it possible to do it on API 8 level? When i've tried to create activity It requires a minimum SDK version of at least 14. The tasks app is also minimum require 8 (android 2.2).

Comment: @user1587263 Try to use ActionBarSherlock http://actionbarsherlock.com/. It supports Android 2.X.

Comment: @user1587263 Download sample codes of ActionBarSherlock and try to find the samples you can start coding from.